# How to know URI from was downloaded ActiveX control

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, activex

I have .NET(C#) ActiveX contol that was downloaded into IE from some URI, for example http://somehost/controlfolder/mycontrol.dll. That control have to download files from host via relative URI. By URI 'files/file.ext' control have to download 'http://somehost/controlfolder/files/file.ext'.

How my control can know main part of URI to construct from relarive URI full URI?

UPD0: I'm using `<object>` tag for definition control in native html(without using ASP.NET).
 
UPD1: Is it possible to know server path without assigning public control property from Javascript?

Comment: in this time i'm only testing control and object tag looks like: <object id="myControl1" name="myControl1" 
   classid="ClassLibrary1.dll#ClassLibrary1.UserControl1" width="250px" height="250px"></object>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ideas:

1. From javascript, set a property on your control to the root url.
   myControl.RootUrl = window.location.replace ("default.aspx", "");
2. From your aspx (or whatever engine you're using).

   <object codebase='http://somehost/controlfolder/mycontrol.dll' ...>
      <param name="RootUrl" value="<% =Request.ApplicationPath + "/controlfolder/" %>"/>
   </object>

Comment: It's good idea about assigning from JS but i'm constrained in adding additional properties to control for some kind of reasons.

Comment: @Alex, are the constraints technical (like it doesn't work) or like you don't want someone to hack it?

Comment: Control interface that i must provide does not contain appriorate methods(properties)

Comment: I suppose you could create and sign your own control which wraps the control that you can't improve the interface.

Comment: This interface for control consumers. Now this not so important. Maybe you can help me with other question about control(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479146/what-the-right-way-to-sign-activex-control-and-grant-permission)?