# What the right way to sign activex control and grant permission

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, permissions, activex

I have activex C# control for IE. That contol downloaded from some host. Control does some work that needs special permissions(IE shows window with information that my control cannot do operation without permission). I spend a lot of time googling and reading many topics about similiar situations. I understood that I must do following things:
1. Sign control assembly with strong key.
2. Grant permission to assembly.
I generated strong key with VS2010 tools. After that my control stopped displaying on page(if don't use signing control displaying is normal). I know about gacutil /cdl, it doesn't help.
I decided that after granting permission, control displaying will be OK, but my opinion was wrong. I granted permission for assembly via command `caspol -addgroup 1 -url http://myhostname/myAdditionPathToControlAssembly/control.dll FullTrust` (about caspol utility describes  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz(v=vs.80).aspx). 
After all my control does not displaying.

What the right way to sign activex control and grant permission to solve my problems?

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer is probably preventing you from initializing your control.  You'll need to mark the control as **Safe for Scripting** and **Safe for Initialization**.  This [document](http://www.olavaukan.com/2010/08/creating-an-activex-control-in-net-using-c/) describes how.  That will at least get you started.  If you have further, more detailed questions, let us all know.